# Where to specify consumerKey and consumerSecret for Twitter login in MVC 6?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity-2

Every time there is a new version of .NET Framework, the framework for authentication using external logins is overhauled!

The external login documentation link for MVC 6, http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532715, is missing.

The initialization now uses `IApplicationBuilder` instead of `IAppBuilder` in the previous version. The `useTwitterAuthentication` method now does not take `consumerKey` and `consumerSecret` parameters. How do I specify these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `project.json` file, in the `dependencies` section:

```
"Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Twitter": "1.0.0-rc1-final"
```

Then, in `Startup.cs`:

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    // Other code here

    app.UseTwitterAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.ConsumerKey = "";
        options.ConsumerSecret = "";
    });

    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Comment: Is it possible now to do it in ConfigureServices method? I think it was possible on the previous versions. 

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<TwitterAuthenticationOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.ConsumerKey = "";
        options.ConsumerSecret = "";
    });
....

Comment: @ArtsiomMarzavin - I might be wrong, but I don't think you can do it that way any more, it got changed in asp.net5 beta 8. http://wildermuth.com/2015/10/20/Upgrading_from_ASP_NET_5_Beta_7_to_Beta_8

Comment: @JamieDunstan is right, `IOptions<>` is no longer supported by the security middleware.